# My edge loops is not complete

Tags: modeling

When I attempt to create an edge loop, it stops at the corner of the mouth. I want it to continue into the upper lip.  [image]

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: please share your file, there must be a problem like a vertex orverlaying or something

Comment: @moonboots i added the file

Comment: @J.Doe i tried the knife thing but i am afraid it wont be the "right" way because this has never happined before while following face tutorials, i am doing this by myself now from what i learned watching tutorials so i needed to do it right and learn what might have gone wrong to not repeat it :s i tried deleting all faces and doing again but the same thing happens .

Comment: @moonboots theres a little white ball under the nose , like a spot which is something i dont know what is, if you see it there, could you tell me what that dot means? it looks the same as the orange one , i dont know how i created this white dot

Comment: the white dot is just the origin of a non-selected object. It looks like it has no vertices, so you can go in Object mode, select it and delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you only have one face (made of 6 vertices) while it looks like you have two (because you've created an edge from a vertex to another). An edge loops can't go through a ngon so it can't go through that face. So delete the face with <kbd>X</kbd> (Delete) > *Only Faces*, and fill the 2 faces.

[image]

What happened? Actually you must have created 2 vertices on the lengths of your face, then, instead of <kbd>J</kbd> to join, which would have separated and created 2 faces, you must have pressed <kbd>F</kbd> to fill, which has created an edge between the 2 vertices, but didn't create 2 faces, and kept the original face.

[image]